# Android Set Visibility Through Another Class Gives Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm having troubles with my game. When the game loop for the SurfaceView is running, I can't change the visbility of the elements I want to make (in)visible.

This is the errors I'm getting, I guess the last four errors are connected and there's the main problem, but I'm not sure if I've done more things stupid.

```
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26727
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that
created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:877)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10275)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8385)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5531)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at   
android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1155)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at     com.coderogden.pongtennis.activities.SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife3C(SingleGameActivity.j    ava:84)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
com.coderogden.pongtennis.views.SingleGameView.outOfBounds(SingleGameView.java:319)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
com.coderogden.pongtennis.views.SingleGameView.update(SingleGameView.java:197)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at  
com.coderogden.pongtennis.other.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:57)
```

This is the involved method that I suppose brings the error (SingleGameActivity.java:84)

```
public static void setInVisLife3C() {

        life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

I would really appreciate all help I can get!
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick respons!

Here is the important part of the code:

Activity-class contains loads of similar methods like this one.

```
public static void setInVisLife3C() {           
        life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Those methods are called from my SurfaceView-class, for instance from here:

```
public void outOfBounds() {

    // Player's side
    if (ball.getY() + ball.getRadius() > box.getBoxBot()) {
        playerLives--;
        playing = false;
        switch (playerLives) {
        case 4:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife5P();
            break;
        case 3:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife4P();
            break;
        case 2:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife3P();
            break;
        case 1:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife2P();
            break;
        case 0:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife1P();
            playerLoses();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called from another method called update() which is also located in the SurfaceView-class!

The update() method is then called from the main thread (game loop) here:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;

        // Try locking the canvas
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // Update game state here!
                    this.gameView.update();
                    More code down here!
```

Please tell me if you need more code to help me! :)

Comment: The error is right there in the logcat, you pretty much can't misunderstand or misinterpret it: `CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that
created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: So you can set the visibility only from the GUI thread, and not from the thread in which your game is running. Use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()` to pass information between threads

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! However, I don't know where to put that piece of code hehe... I'm calling serVisibility from my Activity-class at the moment. Because when I tried to do it from a view class in another project (not surfaceview) it didn't work even to initialize them.

Comment: Well if you want a specific answer than we need to see your code. Without it we can just guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I edited the main question for you to see the important code. I would be really happy if you could help me out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can have multiple threads running simultaneously.  Think of them as multiple roads that go to the same place.  Only the UI Thread, or main road, is allowed to make changes to the UI, so if you're working in another thread, you need to tell your app to first jump back to the UI Thread and them make your visibility change.  Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! However, I don't know where to put that piece of code hehe... I'm calling serVisibility from my Activity-class at the moment. Because when I tried to do it from a view class in another project (not surfaceview) it didn't work even to initialize them.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I should put all setVisibility-methods directly in the main thread class and let the SurfaceView-class call them from there?

Comment: It should work almost anywhere that life3C can represent your View.  I'm afraid you'll have to experiment with this a bit.  There's plenty of StackOverflow support for using runOnUiThread.  The accepted procedure here is to start a new question if you then need help implementing that function.  And don't forget to upvote or mark it as your answer if you like it. That give you rep here too.

Comment: I edited the main question for you to see the important code. I would be really happy if you could help me out! :)